# Ajustar volumen de la música en Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo un problema, estoy intentando poder silenciar o desilenciar la música que tengo puesta en toda la aplicación desde el menú ajustes, lo máximo que he logrado ha sido silenciarlo a cambio de silenciar todo el sonido multimedia del móvil, pero busco sólo silenciar el de la aplicación. Viendo en diversos foros me recomendaron crear un setVolume e igualar el sonido a 0, pero me aparece la música silenciada desde el inicio. Dejo abajo la clase que maneja el sonido:

```
public class AudioService extends Service {

static final int MUTE = 1 ,DECREASE=2, INCREASE = 3, START = 4, PAUSE = 5, STOP=6 ;
Boolean shouldPause = false;
MediaPlayer loop;
private void startLoop() {
    if (loop == null) {
        loop = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.musicasadness);
    }
    if (!loop.isPlaying()) {
        loop.setLooping(true);
        loop.start();
    }
}
private void mute() {loop.setVolume(0.00f, 0.00f);}
private void decrease() {
    loop.setVolume(0.2f, 0.2f);
}

private void increase() { loop.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f); }

private void start() {
    startLoop();
    shouldPause = false;
}

private void pause() {
    shouldPause = true;
    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (shouldPause) {
                        loop.pause();
                    }
                }
            }, 100);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Creating service");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("")
                .setContentText("").build();

        startForeground(1, notification);
    }
}
private void stop(){
    shouldPause=true;
    loop.pause();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Intent received");

    try {
        int actionDefault = 0;
        int action = actionDefault;

        if (intent != null) {
            if (intent.hasExtra("action")) {
                action = intent.getIntExtra("action", actionDefault);
            }
        }

        switch (action) {

            case INCREASE:
                increase();
                break;
            case DECREASE:
                decrease();
                break;
            case START:
                start();
                break;
            case PAUSE:
                pause();
                break;
            case STOP:
                stop();
                break;
            case MUTE:
        }       mute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (loop != null) loop.release();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent2) {
    return null;
}}
```

Gracias de antemano, cualquier ayuda o idea es bienvenida.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> me recomendaron crear un setVolume e igualar el sonido a 0, pero me
> aparece la música silenciada desde el inicio.

antes de iniciar la reproducción define el volumen:

```
...
...
if (!loop.isPlaying()) {
    loop.setLooping(true);

    loop.setVolume(100,100); //Define volumen

    loop.start();
}
...
...
```

Comment: He intentado exactamente lo que me has puesto arriba, y sigue sin funcionar, gracias de todas maneras